# See Methods Called Through UnityEvents in Performance Tab

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have this script that has **UnityEvent** called on **FixedUpdate**. The idea is that I attach various methods to this **OnFixedUpdate** through the Editor like this:

[image]

This is the **Brain** script where this **OnFixedUpdate** resides:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;

public class Brain : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, FoldoutGroup("Fixed Update")]
    private UnityEvent OnFixedUpdate = null;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        OnFixedUpdate.Invoke();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that in the **Performance** tab I only see the **Brain.OnFixedUpdate** method called. I can't see what specific methods were called through this **OnFixedUpdate**:

[image]

Is there a simple way to see the methods that are being called through **OnFixedUpdate**?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
for(int i=0;i<OnFixedUpdate.GetPersistentEventCount();i++){
Debug.Log(OnFixedUpdate.GetPersistentMethodName(i));
}
```

Comment: Could elaborate your response to make it more useful ? Where should your code be added? How does it solves the problem?

Comment: As the op calls his OnFixedUpdate in FixedUpdate he could use it after the call. He could also use this in a coroutine yielding in a true loop and call this piece of code every x seconds. Depends on how often to check for this information. There is no: "put it there and there you go". He could also use this in the Start Method if the event is not changing.